# what to do with IndexError: list index out of range?

Tags: python, selenium

hello so im trying to use selenium for clicking on some buttons in the instagram site but while im running the code this message appears and makes the script crash

```py
button2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

for another button i set the value of under the bracket to 0 and it worked but now i cant fix other buttons with that solution

```py
button2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")[0]
button2.click()
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: It's because your first instance is not returning any elements.

Comment: Can you share the html of the 2 buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")
```

gets back a list. The list can have zero or more entries. When your code indexes into that list, like this

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")[0]
```

it is trying to retrieve the first element of the list. But that means that it is assuming that there is at least one element in the list. The error `list index out of range` is telling you that assumption is false: the list, in this case, is empty.

Comment: if i leave it without the number under the [] i ll get this error 
File "C:\Users\123\Desktop\Works\instagram\login.py", line 20, in <module>
    button2.click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: Fiddling with the indexing syntax is not going to fix the fact that your `find_elements_by_xpath()` call isn't finding anything. There is a issue with your `xpath` and that is what you have to fix. If you want to click the button you have to arrange for `find_elements_by_xpath()` to return at least one button. It's not finding any.